# Как определить длину строки string С++?

Tags: c++, c, строки

Как вернуть длину строки без использования `size, sizeof, strlen`?

Comment: Пройти до нулевого символа?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size

Comment: @Harry, а наличие нулевого символа разве обязательно? Мне кажется, решение должно быть связано c `end()-begin()`, ну или distance

Comment: `std::find`....

Comment: а что такое длинна строки? в utf-8 строках число занятых строкой байтов не будет совпадать с кол-вом символов

Comment: @vp_arth В `.c_str()` - да :)

Comment: Во-первых выберите язык, С или С++. А во вторых, что вы называете строкой? Массив символов или `std::string`?

Answer (score 1):

А так можно?

```
string s;

cout << s.length();
```

О `length` у вас ничего не сказано.

Или

```
cout << end(s)-begin(s);
```